# azure dw limit error

Tags: azure-synapse

I scheduled around 70 concurrent queries using 70 logins to stress test Azure DW (DWU 200) and after a while started getting this error

```
[Execute SQL Task] 
Error: Executing the query "SELECT Distinct S.[Nurse ID],S.[Trust Code],S.[Loc..." failed with the following error: "110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. 
Details: 
Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Workers.DmsSqlNativeException, Message: NativeOdbcConnection.Open, error in OdbcConnectionCreate: SqlState: HY000, NativeError: 10928, 'Error calling: SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR *) L"SELECT @@SPID", SQL_NTS), SQL return code: -1 | 
SQL Error Info: SrvrMsgState: 1, SrvrSeverity: 20,  Error <1>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 1600 and has been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for assistance. | 
ConnectionString: Driver={pdwodbc};APP=TypeC01-DmsNativeReader:DB22\mpdwsvc (69820)-ODBC;Trusted_Connection=yes;AutoTranslate=no;Server=\\.\pipe\DB.22-f8e91ff83e68\sql\query, ConnectionPooling: 1 | Error calling: pConn->Create(connectionString, useConnectionPooling, packetSize, connectionLoginTimeout, environmentSettings, spid) | state: FFFF, number: 19183, active connections: 266', Connection String: Driver={pdwodbc};APP=TypeC01-DmsNativeReader:DB22\mpdwsvc (69820)-ODBC;Trusted_Connection=yes;AutoTranslate=no;Server=\\.\pipe\DB.22-f8e91ff83e68\sql\query".
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

But I can't find a corresponding 1600 limit, neither can I understand how I could have hit it? Any help would be truly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've seen this error running one (1) concurrent query on a DWU100  ADW system - An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Please use this Error ID when contacting your Administrator for assistance. EID:(xxxxx)[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 1600 and has been reached.

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the [concurrency article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency/) on Azure.com? You are stress testing at 70 concurrent queries at a scale level that will, by design begin queueing those requests. My suspicion is that your queue of queued requests is increasing throughout your load test until you hit one of the [limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits/) in the system. The limit I expect you are hitting is the number of open sessions.

If you would like to be certain that is the case then you would need to open a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket/). However, I would also suggest increasing the DWU to a higher figure if you want to run at 70 concurrent queries in a saturated load test.

Comment: Hi JRJ,Thanks for the response. Yes I have read the concurrency article but it doesn't state any resource limits that might be exceeded at 70 sessions with one query each. I did open the support ticket and Azure are working on it to find out which limit is being exceeded.